# How can we compare request parameters of a request against an array of strings in Nginx

Tags: nginx

In Nginx, we can compare request parameters of a request like this.

```
location / {
if ( $arg_cmd = "export_query" ) {
    add_header x-served-from "replica";
    proxy_pass http://replica-first;
    break;
}
...
```

Currently, we are trying redirect requests with some specific params to a different server. These parameters are in hundreds.

How can we do parameter matching against an array in nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map $arg_cmd $replica {
  "export_query" replica-first;
}

server {
  ...
  location / {
    if ($replica) {
      add_header x-served-from $replica;
      proxy_pass http://$replica;
      break;
    }
  }
  ...
```

Documentation on `map` is [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html).

Note: using variables in `proxy_pass` will require [resolver](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).

Comment: You should move the if condition outside the location block and place it within the server block before any location directives to prevent unexpected results with requests not matching the if condition which are processed within the same location. Setting `default` to an empty string within a map is not necessary, without a default parameter the variable will be empty if none of the conditions in the directive are met. If your matching/redirect needs are more complex you can pass requests to an upstream server and redirect using the `x-Accel-Redirect` header value returned from upstream

Comment: @miknik Thanks for the suggestions! One note: [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) is scoped inside `location`, it cannot be used outside of it.